# VB.net Reading csv file - OleDBDatReader returns only numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have following code that reads data using OleDbDataReader.

The funny thing is that I can only return numbers although I converted to string.

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
Dim fileloc = Server.MapPath("~/test/")
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileloc + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'"
cn.Open()

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM feed.csv"

Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
    Response.Write(reader("Stock Number").ToString)
End While
reader.Close()
cn.Close()
```

So I opened the csv file with test and looked the data.

When ever "Stock Number" has string, it doesn't not return data.

IM-95-189-012  ----> returns blank

2241   -----> returns 2241

2241B  -----> returns blank

This is the first time I work with OleDbDataReader.

Any idea what's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are always trying to get a string value, then use GetString.  If you need more info, check the [knowledge base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stkwe6zb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
Response.Write(reader.GetString("Stock Number"))
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115658/when-reading-a-csv-file-using-a-datareader-and-the-oledb-jet-data-provider-how) has a direct impact on this.  Answer is for C#, but should be convertible to VB.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code but I'm getting "Input string was not in a correct format" Error. I've been googling and found this site. This person is getting exactly same issue. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/268732/Csharp-upload-csv-column-data-type-problem

Comment: Interesting.  If I see anything else regarding this, I'll let you know.

Comment: Edited above to include link to solution for C#.

Comment: I guess I need to create Schema.ini file... Anyway, Thank you so much!

Comment: Not a problem.  I have a feeling one of my next projects involves something similar, so I will consider this research!