# Why the data in datatable is convert into INT type

Tags: c#, datatable, rounding

I have a txt file, here is some sample data:

```
Id,PriceOne,Company,PriceTwo,PriceThree
11,15.3599997,Japan ltd,12.23,3.1777777
12,,Koyoto ltd,,0
13,86.25,New Wor,-1289519.44,2536.1245627
......
```

I use this commandText to read the txt file's data into datatable:

```
 string connString = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" 
                   + filePath + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;";
        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection odbcConn = new OdbcConnection(connString))
            {
                odbcConn.Open();
                OdbcCommand oleComm = new OdbcCommand();
                oleComm.Connection = odbcConn;

                oleComm.CommandText = string.Empty;
                if (fileName.ToLower().Contains("fairvalue"))
                 oleComm.CommandText = "select * from [" + fileName + "#txt]";
                else
                 oleComm.CommandText = "select * from [" + fileName + "#csv]";
                OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(oleComm);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, fileName);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
       }
```

but when I debugging the datatable, I got the reslut like below:

```
Id PriceOne    Company      PriceTwo  PriceThree
11 15.3599997  Japan ltd    12        3
12             Koyoto ltd   0
13 86.25       New Wor      -1289519  2536
......
```

I don't know why the PriceTwo column and PriceThree columns' value are changed to INT, well, PriceOne column's value is right ?

Could anyone help me? thx.

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Consider using filehelpers - www.filehelpers.com. It's free, and will allow you to specify the column specification on import.

Comment: @Amar Palsapure, I have modified the content and add more code details, above code is what I used to extract data from a txt file(the txt file's data is splited by comma, so the ODBC object can read it by .net)

Comment: @dash, thx for your advice, but I think it's too late for me to change my code.

Comment: What is text encoding of csv/txt doc?

Comment: In which case you can try using a schema.ini file. This file will allow you to specify the column types, and has already been covered on SO here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115658/when-reading-a-csv-file-using-a-datareader-and-the-oledb-jet-data-provider-how Note that this should work for the ODBC connection too. You can even get windows to write the schema.ini file for you - http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12566

Comment: @dash, thx, you give me the right answer.

Comment: thx for dash's answer, I have solved the problem by below method:

1. create a file named Schema.ini under the same location where your txt file is in.
2. open the Schema.ini file and add below content:

     [Mytext.txt]
     ColNameHeader=True
     MaxScanRows=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the database table([priceHistory#txt]) in that two columns having what datatype.
it must be int datatype.

change the datatype of "PriceTwo" and 
PriceThree" from integer to decimal(18,2)

it will work fine.

```
Id PriceOne    Company      PriceTwo (should be decimal)  PriceThree (should be decimal)
11 15.3599997  Japan ltd    12        3
12             Koyoto ltd   0
13 86.25       New Wor      -1289519  253
```

check it and let me know.

Comment: the data was not extract from database ,but from a txt file, so there is no data type for it.

Comment: How can I add decimal for it?

Comment: You need to manually create datatable with required columns and specify datatype to that column and finally add this datatable to dataset and fill that dataset["datatable"]

Comment: I think I have got the answer, I need a ini file to specify my columnheader type . thanks for help :D