# Read a CSV file into a Data Grid View (Win Forms)

Tags: c#, xml, forms, datagrid, csv

Is there an easy way to read the contents of a CSV file/XML Sitemap (will just be a bunch of URLS) into a Datagrid view in a win form?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a good article for doing this located here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16951/Populating-data-from-a-CSV-file-to-a-DataGridView the code is in VB.NET but it should be easy to convert either using your own knowledge or using an online conversion tool such as www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

How about using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/). This can read delimited or fixed length files which you map to a type.

In your case the type will contain a string Url.

Put these into a collection and databind to that.

Something like:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Row
{
    public string Url;

}
```

and then to read into memory:

```
FileHelperEngine<Row> engine = new FileHelperEngine<Row>();
engine.ReadFile("input.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

read the csv file to a dataset, and then set the dataset as the datasource of the dataGridView . Follow this link for populating the dataset: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/ReadcommaseparatedvalueintoDataSet.htm

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are common data sources accessible from OLEDb data provider. Fill a DataTable with them and then set the DataTable as DataSource for the GridView.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115658/when-reading-a-csv-file-using-a-datareader-and-the-oledb-jet-data-provider-how).