# CSV file one of the column contains both integer and string values, uploading using C# Oledb provide string values are not loading

Tags: c#

CSV file one of the column contains both integer and string values, uploading using C# Oledb provide string values are loding.

Reason for that more values are in integer datatype, string values are not loading. If string values are more both integer and string values loading.

Comment: the first step to solving the problem would be you posting some code and sample data

Comment: I got solution from below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115658/when-reading-a-csv-file-using-a-datareader-and-the-oledb-jet-data-provider-how.

Answer (score -1):

Change datatype of column as String in excel then try to upload the data ...

Comment: That is daily task run at midnight

Comment: Thanks for you quick response i got the solution from below link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115658/when-reading-a-csv-file-using-a-datareader-and-the-oledb-jet-data-provider-how