# OLEDB reading CSV file returns first column only

Tags: c#, sql, csv, oledb

I'm trying to read a pipe separated text file. First lines are

```
"BewerberID"|"Druck"|"Druckdatum"|"HistorieID"|"Bearbeiter"|"BewZuBewGruppeID"|"Bemerkung"
"12586"|"EinladungOFD.dot                                  "|"03.02.2003 00:00:00"|"162"|"Petersen  "|"20295"|"ungültig"
"12807"|"EinladungOFD.dot                                  "|"27.02.2003 00:00:00"|"258"|"Petersen  "|"20617"|""
"12807"|"EinladungOFD.dot                                  "|"28.02.2003 00:00:00"|"270"|"Petersen  "|"20617"|""
```

Below is the LINQpad script i'm using. It runs perfectly, but does return values from the first colum only.

```
string mySelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Historie.CSV";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection
("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\;" + 
   "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;FMT=Delimited(|)\"");
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = mySelectQuery;
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Dump();
rdr.Close();
connection.Close();
```

This returns the first column only.

```
BewerberID 
12586 
12807 
12807
```

I tried switching to column names `SELECT BewerberID, Druck FROM Historie.CSV` but get an error stating "At least one parameter has no value". (BTW: `SELECT BewerberID FROM Historie.CSV` does work and returns the same as *)

What do i have to do to get all columns back?

Comment: Perhaps try defining a schema file, as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115658/when-reading-a-csv-file-using-a-datareader-and-the-oledb-jet-data-provider-how).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file named `schema.ini` in the same folder as `Historie.CSV` (in this case `C:\`). The file should have the following contents:

```
[Historie.csv]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=True
```

Then try rerunning the code.

Some links:

- [When reading a CSV file using a DataReader and the OLEDB Jet data provider, how can I control column data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/116111/111794)
- [Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver)

Comment: Works perfectly. Although i'm confused, as this is no more information as is  given in the connection string. Does this mean, OLEDB is buggy and does not read the information correctly?